# UILabel.text shortening and appending "..."

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, uilabel

I have an UILabel that I want to contain a preview of a long string. It should be a 1-line-label, and should be populated with a maximum number of Characters and then append "..." at the end of the UILabel.text. Now i could do that manually, but I'd really like to calculate all of that stuff and do it dynamically, as the label is a subview of UITableViewCell and when turning the device, it should be possible to stretch it and calculate again.

Any ideas?

P.S. Sorry for any spelling mistakes, I'm not a native speaker..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question well, but isn't this supported anyway, if you set the `UILabel`'s `lineBreakMode` to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that was so damn obvious. Didn't see the wood because of all the trees. Thank you!